# Public image url from Google Gdata Contacts API

Tags: gdata-api

I'm trying to display related users through the Google GData Contacts API.

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
Query q = new Query(feedUrl);
q.setMaxResults(max);
q.setUpdatedMin(q.getUpdatedMin());

ContactFeed feed = client.query(q, ContactFeed.class);

for(ContactEntry item : feed.getEntries()){
  [...]
}
```

I know that there is a public image url for profiles on Google.

```
https://www.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
```

However, when I retrieve a user's contacts, there just doesn't seem to be a field available to reference that user_id.